# Why is the declension of the verb is for feminine singular?

Tags: грамматика, глаголы, склонение

Why is the declension of the verb is for feminine singular?

> группа туристов **хотела** бы пообедать.

Isn't `группа туристов` plural here?

Comment: Why would "группа" be plural? Do you say "group of tourists **have** arrived at the camp" in English?

Comment: @Abakan In British English, that is in fact what you say.

Comment: @Abakan, I have found some info on the net, and it said that both singular and plural are possible in English. I even came across such a sentence "..BE has a much stronger preference for a plural verb with a group of people.."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, "группа туристов" is singular. The fact that group denotes a set of objects does not change the fact that the word itself is singular.

Compare "группа туристов заблудилась в лесу" and "группы туристов переходили вброд речку кто где".

As an example of seemingly more complicated constructs think of "пара групп туристов" - it's a couple of groups - and it's still singular )

Comment: "группа" is feminine singular. That is why "хотела" is used, right?

Comment: @xpr34 yes, precisely

Answer (score 5):

While Russian does [hesitate between singular and plural](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo) with such collective nouns as **ряд, большинство, меньшинство, часть,** or **множество**, the word **группа** doesn't have the quasi-numeral, for lack of a better term, properties of the English "group". In other words, it's thought of as an entity comprised of people, rather than a set of people.